# Liquibase minimum set of previleges for mysql

Tags: mysql, liquibase, privileges

We have just introduced liquibase for schema migration in our team.
Our applications run mysql version 5.7

We have set up a user : "liquibase"  to apply our changesets. However
because of company policies we cannot grant "ALL PREVILEGES" to this
user.

We have granted permissions like ("SELECT, CREATE, ALTER") etc however there are always some permissions that are missing and we have to manually keep adding to the set of privileges. We do not know what privileges are missing until we actually run liquibase.

Does anyone know what is the minimum set of previleges that must be granted to be able apply all possible changesets.

Comment: As far as I understand, `liquibase` by itself doesn't require any privileges. Database user's actions require privileges, so the set of privileges your user requires is dependent on what you intend to accomplish via changesets.

Comment: Liquibase needs to have authorization / authentication when connecting to DB for applying changesets. If you use the schema owner or a privileged DBA user as user, you have full rights on all schema objects to apply all your changes. Otherwise you need to take care of specific DDL rights...